# Unable to output variables into html

Tags: javascript, html, variables, output, getelementbyid

The following script open correctly a link with a formatted date when i click the button on my html page.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var date = /*my script that collects a specific date*/ ;
        var [yyyy, mm, dd] = date.toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-');

        document.getElementById("cid").innerHTML = dd;
        document.getElementById("cim").innerHTML = mm;



             window.open( "https://www.mywebsite.com/" +yyyy );

});
```

the problem : I can't display into the html page the data from the variables.
I'm using this code :

```
Date values : <span id="cid"></span> / <span id="cim"></span>
```

Is it Maybe because the script is triggered only when i click the #button ? In any case I would like to display the values on the page before the button is clicked. 
How can i do this ? thanks

Comment: Store the logic in a function and just call the function on page load. have you tried that?

Comment: I tried to put into the document ready function, but it doesn't work. I guess if maybe I'm doing a trivial javscript grammar mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I dont understand what ypou want to achieve but for me everything works good when you move your logic outside click function.

```
function updateDate(){
  console.log('Updated!')
  const date = new Date();
  const [yyyy, mm, dd] = date.toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-');

  document.getElementById("cid").innerHTML = dd;
  document.getElementById("cim").innerHTML = mm;  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  updateDate();

  $('#button').click(function(e) {  
    updateDate();
  });
})
```

Look on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aofd5vne/1/

Comment: I tried your code, but it loads the destination page immediately instead of waiting for the click on the button. Is there any way this can be fixed?

Comment: Yes, window.open add in button click function after updateDate function. Don't add window open in updateDate function

Comment: I'm very new to javascript and I'm trying to fix the problem of the automatic load but no luck for the moment. maybe you can help me ? i think it's a javascript grammar issue